# How do I unroot my Evo (using unrevoked 3.21)

Tags: htc-evo, unrooting

O.k so I have an H.T.C Evo with Froyo 2.2, and I recently rooted it using unRevoked 3.21 but now i'm having some issues with my phone and would like to return it back to sprint. How do I remove the root and change the evo back to stock version so I can take my phone into sprint for a checkup. Can someone pleaaaaaaasssssssse help me? My phone is moving like a turtle.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with [this method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=780141&highlight=recovery+image). It's basically just two steps:

1. If you used Unrevoked Forever on
   your phone, then flash their S-ON
   tool.
2. Flash a stock PC36IMG.zip
   from HBoot.

There's also the [RUU method](http://forum.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-roms-hacks/19278-how-unroot-return-stock.html), though I think you'd still need to run the S-ON tool if you used Unrevoked Forever (I don't believe the RUU will re-enable S-ON). Either one of these should get you back to a stock unrooted system.

Comment: The RUU is basically a nice, executable version of step 2.  The OP will need to flash S-ON first, then either flash the RUU or the ROM extracted from it.